# Compile two separate CSS files with Less2css in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have this structure

```
includes/
    less/
        main.less
    css/
        main.css
```

And it works fine but I now need this:

```
includes/
    less/
        main.less
        admin.less
    css/
        main.css
        admin.css
```

I have a less file that is compiled into main.css.
And now I also have admin.less that I want to compile into admin.css.
But I can only specify one input and output in less2css settings:

```
"less2css":
{
    "autoCompile": true,
    "minify": true,
    "main_file": "/includes/less/core.less",
    "outputFile": "/includes/css/main.css"
}
```

How can I do this?
Or are there better compilators with compile @ save for Sublime Text out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of compiling inside of Sublime Text, I recommend you look into an external build system, like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Gulp can watch your files for changes and then do things based on that. If you have node and npm setup, run these commands to set up gulp and a less plugin for gulp.

(NOTE: It doesn't even have to be a nodejs project at all. Also, I'd recommend making a package.json and adding node_modules to your gitignore, but that's irrelevant for now.)

```
npm install -g gulp
npm install --save-dev gulp
npm install --save-dev gulp-less
```

Then, create a file at the root of your project called *gulpfile.js*, and enter the following text:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var less = require("gulp-less");

// Task to compile all less files in the project
gulp.task("less", function() {
    gulp.src("includes/less/*.less")
        .pipe(less())
        .on("error", console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("includes/css"));
});

// Task to watch less files for changes
gulp.task("watch", function() {
    gulp.watch("includes/less/*.less", ["less"]);
});

// Compile everything once and then watch for changes.
gulp.task("default", ["less", "watch"]);
```

Run *gulp less* to compile your less once, *gulp watch* to immediately start watching, and plain *gulp* to compile everything once then start watching.

As you can see, gulp is very powerful. You can do things like minify JavaScript, compile CoffeeScript, LiveReload your browser and more.

(I apologize for any errors, I'm on my iPad.)

EDIT: iPad formatting mistakes.